# formで得たデータを配列に入れてcsvで出力したい

Tags: php

DBは使わず配列でcsv出力をしたいと思っています。

現在アンケートフォームを作っていて、

```
<form action="confirm_enq.php" method="get">
<p>名前: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>

<p>年齢: <input type="text" name="age"></p>
<p>性別: 
    男<input type="radio" name="gender" value="男">
    女<input type="radio" name="gender" value="女">
</p>

<p>趣味:</p>
<p>
        料理<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="料理">
        旅行<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="旅行">
        プログラミング<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="プログラミング">
        野球観戦<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="野球観戦">
        ダンス<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="ダンス">
        カメラ<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="カメラ">
        カフェ巡り<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="カフェ巡り">
        読書<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="読書">
        ゲーム<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="ゲーム">
        カラオケ<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="カラオケ">
</p>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

上記のファイルを

```
 <?php 
     $name=htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"],ENT_QUOTES);
     $email=htmlspecialchars($_GET['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
     $age=htmlspecialchars($_GET['age'],ENT_QUOTES);
     $gender=htmlspecialchars($_GET['gender'],ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<body>

<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>

<br>
<?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_GET["age"]; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_GET["gender"]; ?>
<br>
<?php foreach($_GET["hobby"] as $value){
   echo "{$value}, "; 
   } ?>
```

このconfirm_enq.phpでgetしています。

やりたいことは、ここで得た回答をdata.csvで出力したいのですが、
配列に入れて出力する書き方がわかりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ほとんど完成しているように見えます。
ただ単に、ファイルに書き出したいだけであれば、
confirm_enq.phpの一番したのphpの部分に、数行ファイル操作用のコマンドを書き加えればよいはずです。

具体的には、

```
foreach($_GET["hobby"] as $value){
   echo "{$value}, "; 
}
```

の部分を、下記に変えてください。

```
$myfile = fopen("data.csv", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
foreach($_GET["hobby"] as $value){
   $content = "{$value}, ";
   echo $content;
   fwrite($myfile, $content);
}
fwrite($myfile, "\n");
fclose($myfile)
```

説明としましては、
fopenを使用して、ファイルにアクセスする変数(ファイルハンドル=$myfile)を作成します。
その後、fwriteコマンドを使用し、どのファイルにsaveしたいのか(ファイルハンドル$myfile)を指定し、そのあとに、記入したい内容(ここでは($content)を書いておきます。
最後にfcloseを使って、ファイルの書き出し終了を指示しています。

補足としては、上記のものでは、書き出すたびにdata.csvの一番下に新しい情報と付け加えていくという形にしています。（たぶんKojimaさんはそのようにしたいのではないかと思いまして。）

しかし、data.csvを毎回書き換えたい(overwrite)したい場合は、

```
変更前:
fopen("data.csv", "a") //"a"は、"append（書き足し）"

変更後:
fopen("data.csv", "w") //"w"は、"write(書き出し)"
```

に変更すればいいですよ。

良いアンケートフォームができるといいですね。頑張ってください。